# iphone : revoke distribution certificate and push notifications

Tags: iphone, notifications, distribution

I have an iPhone app with **push notifications enabled** and it's working pretty well. But my mac mini just "died" and I realize I did forgot to backup my public / private keys :/ So I guess my only solution now is to create new certificates (both developer and distribution) so I can continue my work ... but what happens with my push notifications?

I mean : **the pem file** used for my push notification server is "linked" to my current **distribution certificate**. What happens if i revoke my certificate?

- Will my push notifications still work ?
- If yes, what will happen when I'll submit a new version of the binary?
- If not, do I "only" need to create a new pem file?

Did any of you experienced such a situation?

Comment: what happened? Did push notifications still work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can speak from personal experience, that if you release a new binary under your new certificate, your users will experience no disruption in the orderly upgrading of your application. The same thing happened to me, and my concern was that when I submitted an update to my application that things would get confused - and even worse - users would loose the data they saved which was associated with my application. (In either preferences, or the sqlite database).

Everything worked seamlessly however, despite the new version being submitted as signed by a completely different certificate as the original.

I have **not** done this however involving push notifications.